# Facebook App Request not being sent in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, request

I have my app set up to send facebook app requests. I get the popup screen to pick friends and when I click on send button, the popup disappears. And I get a request ID printed out in the console as well.

Although the friends that I have selected to send the request has not received the app request.

I have facebook sdk 3.1 which works well with other activities such as posting to user's walls etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicates:

- [Facebook iOS SDK - Sending a facebook user an app request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453040/facebook-ios-sdk-sending-a-facebook-user-an-app-request)
- [How to Send App request to facebook friends through facebook iOS sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148244/how-to-send-app-request-to-facebook-friends-through-facebook-ios-sdk)

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148244/how-to-send-app-request-to-facebook-friends-through-facebook-ios-sdk) on the second link provides a step by step procedure on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your facebook app id is same in both developer page and info in xcode next, enable sandbox mode and must fill canvas url [under app on facebook category] in developer page.

```
NSString *facebookID = @"Your friend facebook id";
    NSMutableDictionary* params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:facebookID forKey:@"to"];

    NSString *message = @"SOME_MESSAGE";
    NSString *title = @"TITLE";

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                  message:message
                title:title
                parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                        if (error)
                    {
                    // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                        NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                    {
                    // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                        NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Request Sent. %@", params);
                    }
        }}];
```